# How to lock my screen?

Tags: 11.10, lock-screen

I can't enable lock screen mode in my laptop and also in my PC. I went to system setting > screen > lock
Ctrl+Alt+L :
Nothing happens!
the shortcut is there but not works !

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-screensaver :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dassault-systemes-draftsight:i386 : Depends: sendmail:i386 but it is not installable
                                     PreDepends: libdirectfb-extra:i386 (>= 1.2.7-2) but it is not going to be installed
                                     PreDepends: libxcb-render-util0:i386 (>= 0.3.6-1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: what happens if you run `gnome-screensaver-command -l` ?

Comment: nothing happens !

Comment: try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-screensaver` and then try again `gnome-screensaver-command -l`

Comment: I can't ! it says :"You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dassault-systemes-draftsight:i386 : Depends: sendmail:i386 but it is not installable
                                     PreDepends: libdirectfb-extra:i386 (>= 1.2.7-2) but it is not going to be installed
                                     PreDepends: libxcb-render-util0:i386 (>= 0.3.6-1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
"

Comment: ok - we are narrowing down the issue - you've got package issues.  Either remove that draftsight package or try and fix it ... maybe this Q&A helps? http://askubuntu.com/questions/39647/how-do-i-install-draftsight-cad

Comment: I removed it and the re-installation completed without any errors .

Comment: @Mahdiar We don't do "solved" here, so I rolled back your question, you can post how you solved it as an answer at the bottom, and then check the checkmark to mark it solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I installed ubuntu tweak . go to the "Tweaks" part and then to the "Security related" . Then unchecked "Disable lock screen " !
Thats it !

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, I had the same problem. Upvoted. Does anyone know what this actually did?

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

The above keyboard shortcut will lock your screen.

Comment: Thanks But it doesn't work !

Comment: @mahdiar but you just said in the comment on the other answer that it works.

Comment: Sorry !!! I mean I can see the correct shortcut key in the settings but it doesn't work !

Comment: @mahdiar interesting... I think fossfreedom is on the right track in the answer above.

Comment: Works for me!   Upvote.   I have xscreensaver installed but disabled, and in power I tell it never to disable the screen.  But Ctrl-Alt-L is perfect.  Now I can walk away safely while a long copy is running.  Thank you, @James!  It only took about 2 minutes of searching to find your answer.  Pretty cool.

Answer (score 8):

I was reading around & saw that some computers if CON+ALT+L doesn't work to try the "Windows" botton + L (the button with the little Windows logo, if that's the type of computer you're using)
WIN+L ---> It worked on mine, I couldn't find the shortcuts mentioned above so I tried this & it worked! Good luck!!

Comment: That shortcut works in Windows. Does it work in Ubuntu also? (I don't use Unity so I cannot easily test this on my Ubuntu systems.)

Comment: Verified it works on Ubutnu 18.04 running on System76 Oryx Pro

Answer (score 2):

Try screensaver command, and see if this is the keyboard (shortcut) or the application (graphics function) that is not working:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

Also check shortcut:  (should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> )

```
>> System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> System

  Lock screen                                  Ctrl+Alt+l
```

Comment: the fist command doesn't work and the shortcut is ok !

Comment: What error message?  Command not found, etc.

Comment: no error !! nothing happened .

Comment: Try **gnome-screensaver-command -a** to activate.