# Does locking affect running processes?

Tags: lock-screen

I would like to run the updates available to my Ubuntu device with the built-in Software Updater application, but I would like to lock my system for the time of the update for security reasons. (Others can physically access my computer.)

I would like to know if that was possible? I am also interested in any solution using terminal, but I need to make sure that my user is locked during the update.

**edit** My question is not a duplicate, since the real question here is to know whether locking the screen still allows processes started by my user to run, or not. I lock my system on daily basis, have no problems with that. Please confirm if locking doesn't affect the execution of the updater application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lock my screen?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89534/how-to-lock-my-screen)

Comment: @gen Thanks for the clarification about how this question focuses on what happens behind the scenes while [that one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89534/how-to-lock-my-screen) is just about preventing effective user interaction; I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This shortcut locks your system:

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Locking the system does not affect running processes if they expect any interaction.

In the special case of a system update, queries *may* be limited, but not be totally excluded.

E.G.:

```
sudo apt-get --assume-yes update
```

Comment: You should say "locks your desktop"... Because the system can be accessed in other ways (TTY, SSH, ...)

Comment: please see the edit to my question and confirm if locking is useful in this case

Comment: Perhaps you may want to consider in advance what your question is.