# Lock screen Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, security, lock-screen

I am unable to lock my screen either using CTRL-ALT-L or waiting for 5 minutes (inactive time option). After pressing the combination of keys (or waiting the 5 minutes), the screen turns off but it does not ask for any password to return to the desktop. Can anyone help me please? Thank you!

Here are my settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to settings->keyboard. I don't have access to Ubuntu in my office right now. There you can find option like "Shortcut". Find what is the new shortcut key for locking the system.

Comment: So the important information is that the "lock" switch is shown grayed out. So it can not be activated.

Comment: Can you `edit` your question and add the screen image for `System Settings` -> `Power`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem. There was an option in the Unity Tweak Tool that was preventing any screen lock. **Desktop lock checkbox must be disabled**. Thanks to https://askubuntu.com/a/91719/219893

[image: Unity tweak tool desktop lock]

Comment: This worked for me, finally! I installed **Unity Tweak Tool** with `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` but can be found in the Ubuntu Software app. By habit I had been typing the password to launch the system back on so this was a huge vulnerability for me! Thanks @Gatuno !

Answer (score 1):

Enable the "LOCK" switch in the settings "Brightness and Lock" dialog.

**I see that the "LOCK" switch is disabled on your screenshot**.

Then it would ask for a password after blanking screen or pressing CRTL-ALT-L.

To also ask for password after standyby: 
Then you have to ensure that the checkbox "require my password when waking from suspend" is selected.

I have attached a screen shot of my dialog here:
[image]

Comment: Lock switch is only related to his second problem (Lock screen after 'x' min).

Comment: As learner says, there is no "LOCK" switch in that window and the options are disabled. In your picture you can edit the options, but not in mine.

Comment: What I mean is that I cannot edit the Brightess & Lock window, under the Lock section. It is not that the switch is enabled or disabled, I simply cannot change anything in that window (except for the inactivity time combobox)

Comment: Can you create a new user and give him a password. Check if there is possible to enable the "lock" switch?