# draftsight for ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

Is there any edited file for draftsight.deb  so it can work on ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit

I have downloaded the draftsight.deb from the website and tried to install it on my laptop

but I couldn't install it.

If anyone knows an edited deb file please give me the link ...

I have tried other solutions but it seems that I can't follow up with these solutions or they don't work at all

I need it for my work ...
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it could not install due to a missing dependency? You could always extract the contents of the deb using `ar` and copy the files across. Once you run it you will likely be able to tell what is missing. There are other ways to find dependencies that would be more definitive, but they are more involved.

Comment: I tried that and failed to do it right...
Finally I installed the draftsight for windows using Wine
It worked but I am not satisfied ...It is just a trick to keep going but not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo dpkg -i draftsight.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

Draftsight is only available in 32-bit edition (14/01/2014, V1R4 beta). Here is a workaround for the 12.04 edition. Reference can be found in https://askubuntu.com/a/52898/153278 and https://askubuntu.com/a/129635/153278.
1) Install depending packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libdirectfb-extra libxcb-render-util0 libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

2) Then force the system to install draftsight anyway:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture,depends draftSight.deb
```

Works for me in Xubuntu 12.04 (64bit)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need remove dependency in `control` file according to this instruction
[removing dependencies from draftSight.deb](http://linuxaideddesign.blogspot.ru/2012/03/draftsight-and-ubuntu-1204-lts-64bit.html)
I instaled DraftSight, but it didn't start with messages about libraries (libGL, libGLU) then I run:

`sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev ia32-libs`

now it works fine.